Unable to Find Entity for Import or Export of Inventory Adjustment Data D365
I am having trouble locating the entity for Inventory Adjustment in Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations. Despite following the usual procedures, I am unable to access the required entity for making inventory adjustments. Any assistance or guidance on how to find and connect to this specific entity would be greatly appreciated.
I was able to find an entity under the name WarehousesOnHandV2, but it only displays inventory data and does not allow for inventory manipulation.
